# pytest warningsfilter breaks tests using pytest.warns(..)

Tags: python, travis-ci, pytest

I have a strange error using [filterwarnings](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html#pytest-mark-filterwarnings) in pytest.  I'm trying to filter the warnings that are raise on [MDAnalysis](https://github.com/MDAnalysis/mdanalysis). Currently I have the following config.

```
[tool:pytest]
filterwarnings= always
```

Using that config all the tests pass on python 2 and 3 [travis](https://travis-ci.org/MDAnalysis/mdanalysis/builds/275801720). This results in a lot of warnings since MDAnalysis uses a lot of warnings to inform the user about various things. Now to filter the warnings down to see everything except User and some RuntimeWarnings I use the following [config](https://github.com/MDAnalysis/mdanalysis/pull/1661).

```
[tool:pytest]
filterwarnings= all
                  ignore::UserWarning
                  ignore:invalid value encountered in.*:RuntimeWarning
```

Now the some tests fail only on python 2 [Travis](https://travis-ci.org/MDAnalysis/mdanalysis/builds/275871796). The tests check that if a UserWarning is raised. Strangely this only applies to a handful of tests. The mosts tests that use `pytest.warns(UserWarning)` still work fine. I do not understand why this only affects a handful of tests on python 2. Are warnings treated differently on python 2 vs python 3?